# How in CBV correctly redirect user if he dont have permission?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, django-1.11

I want to redirect user to url (`reverse_lazy('dashboard')`) if **Class Based View** is not available to user (he dont have permission). I use next code but it dont redirect user. Whats wrong?

**views.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class UserEditView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'users/edit_user.html'
    form_class = UserEditForm
    model = User
    permission_required = ('auth.change_user')
    login_url = None
    redirect_field_name = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
```

**LOG in terminal**:

```
LevelName: WARNING | Message: Not Found: /accounts/login/
LevelName: WARNING | Message: "GET /accounts/login/?/=/user/50/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2838
```

Also I tried next. If in `settings.py` I set `LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('administration_login')`in terminal I see next log but it dont redirect user:

```
LevelName: INFO | Message: "POST /user/50/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
LevelName: INFO | Message: "GET /login/?/=/user/50/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
LevelName: INFO | Message: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2427
```

**QUESTION**: Can someone say how to make correct redirection to custom url if user don't have permission?

**JS**:

```
$(function () {
    var saveForm = function () {
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: form.attr("method"),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.form_is_valid) {
                    $("#users").html(data.html_users);
                    $("#user-modal").modal("hide");
                }
                else {
                    $("#user-modal .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
                    $("#user-errors").fadeIn("slow");
                    var error_message = "</br>";
                    var json_string = JSON.stringify(data.form_errors);
                    var json_object = jQuery.parseJSON(json_string);
                    $.each(json_object, function(key, value){
                        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                            error_message += value[i] + "</br>";
                        }
                    });
                    $("#user-errors .error-description").html(error_message);
                    setTimeout(function() {$("#user-errors").fadeOut("slow");}, 10000);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $("#user-errors").fadeIn("slow")
                $("#user-errors .error-description").html(thrownError);
                setTimeout(function() {$("#user-errors").fadeOut("slow");}, 10000);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
        });
        return false;
    };

    $("#user-modal").on("submit", ".user-edit-form", saveForm);
});
```

Comment: Note that your `permission_required = ('auth.change_user')` looks confusing. I would either remove the parentheses and use `permission_required = 'auth.change_user'`, or add the comma to make it a tuple and use `permission_required = ('auth.change_user',)`.

Comment: Ok, I make as you said but it dont solve the problem =( Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing `redirect_field_name`. It should be the name of the *field* that stores the next URL, and it defaults to the string `'next'`. Unless you have a good reason to change that you should remove that line and let Django use the default.

Use the `login_url` to configure your view to redirect to the dashboard.

```
class UserEditView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
```

Comment: I tried iyour code but it dont redirect =( In log I see this: `LevelName: INFO | Message: "GET /?next=/user/50/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3449`. In template I see this error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data`. I add my JS code to post, can you check it pls?

Comment: If you're using JavaScript that changes your question completely. I can't help with that.